# Use Doctrine with REST APIs

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine, driver, dbal

Is it possible to use a REST API as Doctrine database?

Regarding the configuration on http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html I can change the "driver" property.

But in the list of allowed drivers there is no one to use a REST API.

What I would like to do is:

```
<?php
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
//..
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'my_rest_api',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'host' => 'localhost:3000',
    'driver' => 'rest',
);
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

// Sends a GET request to localhost:3000/myentity/1 and maps it properly to my configured entity
$entity = $entityManager->find("MyNamespace\Entity\MyEntity", 1);

// Sends a POST request to localhost:3000/myentity
$entity = new MyEntity();
$entityManager->persist($entity);
$entityManager->flush();

// and so on
```

Thank you for your answers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DoctrineRestDriver is exactly doing what you are looking for!

https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

Have fun!